# How can I remove Strings from an ArrayList which contain only whitespace characters?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to remove all strings in a list which contain only whitespace characters. I tried the following code, but some lines were not removed:

```
List<String> getarray = /* ... */;

for (int i = 0; i < getarray.size(); i++) {
    if (getarray.contains(" ").getarray.contains(null)) {
        getarray.remove(i);
    } else {
        System.out.println("a: " + getarray.get(i));
    }
}
```

This does only work for certain inputs, can somebody help me understand why?

[Here is a list of inputs which did not work as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjMPn.jpg)

Comment: You want to remove any line that has only whitespace characters in it? Try `String.trim` and then `String.isEmpty`.

Comment: @krunal look the answer I've post, it's so much quicker and small code ;)

Comment: @azro I agree, your code is smaller and looks nicer, but for people who are just learning to program or are new to Java, it is really hard to understand. I think krunal is trying to understand loops and how strings work, lambdas and the stream api are maybe a bit too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all use some **Iterator**  to iterate and perform your operation of removing elements from ArrayList.

Second to solve your problem of empty string , you could use **trim()** and **isEmpty()** methods

try below code:

```
Iterator<String> it = getarray.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
      String myValue = it.next();
      if (myValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
            it.remove();
      } else {
            System.out.println("a: " + myValue);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Iterators if you want to remove elements. According to Java docs:

> Iterator takes the place of Enumeration in the Java Collections Framework. Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
>   Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
>   Method names have been improved

Try the following code:

```
Iterator<String> itr = getarray.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String value = itr.next();
        if (value.trim().isEmpty()) {
            itr.remove();
        } else {
            System.out.println("a: " + value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll remove ALL element which contains a space, not the empty element ^^

Comment: I misinterpret the question a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand between *element is empty or only composed of spaces* AND *element contain spaces* :

So it's `element.trim().isEmpty()` instead of `element.contains(" ");`

`.trim()` removes spaces at start and at the ens of the `String`

---

So this will do your stuff, it will iterate over the list, and only keep the element which are not empty (or only compsed of spaces)

```
getarray = getarray.stream().filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you wan to print all after just do : `getarray.forEach(System.out::println);`